# wget has different response times for same fetch

Tags: wget

Any ideas why one fetch would fetch a file (big picture in this example) fast while another fetch would fetch same file slow?  Not seeing this issue at home.  Not seeing this issue through ip addresses they map to 192.xx.xx.xx.  Only seeing this issue when the ip is a public ip yet is going through the internal company network.  Any ideas would be helpful.

```
Resolving undisclosed_site... --17:59:05--  http://undisclosed_site.com/LinkOne/195000.jpg
           => `195000.jpg'
Resolving undisclosed_site.com... public_ip
Connecting to undisclosed_site[public_ip]:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK

Length: 2,154,765 [image/jpeg]

    0K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  2%   96.90 KB/s
   50K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  4%  246.31 KB/s
  100K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  7%  641.03 KB/s
  150K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  9%  641.03 KB/s
  200K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 11%  318.47 KB/s
  250K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 14%  641.03 KB/s
  300K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 16%  641.03 KB/s
  350K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 19%  458.72 KB/s
  400K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 21%  641.03 KB/s
  450K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 23%    1.53 MB/s
  500K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 26%  641.03 KB/s
  550K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 28%  806.45 KB/s
  600K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 30%  400.00 KB/s
  650K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 33%    1.04 MB/s
  700K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 35%  793.65 KB/s
  750K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 38%  458.72 KB/s
  800K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 40%  641.03 KB/s
  850K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 42%  641.03 KB/s
  900K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 45%    3.05 MB/s
  950K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 47%  531.91 KB/s
 1000K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 49%  357.14 KB/s
 1050K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 52%  641.03 KB/s
 1100K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 54%  793.65 KB/s
 1150K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 57%  806.45 KB/s
 1200K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 59%  641.03 KB/s
 1250K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 61%  632.91 KB/s
 1300K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 64%  641.03 KB/s
 1350K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 66%    1.58 MB/s
 1400K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 68%  531.91 KB/s
 1450K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 71%  641.03 KB/s
 1500K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 73%  357.14 KB/s
 1550K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 76%  531.91 KB/s
 1600K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 78%    3.05 MB/s
 1650K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 80%  531.91 KB/s
 1700K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 83%  641.03 KB/s
 1750K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 85%  537.63 KB/s
 1800K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 87%  632.91 KB/s
 1850K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 90%  357.14 KB/s
 1900K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 92%  793.65 KB/s
 1950K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 95%  641.03 KB/s
 2000K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 97%  641.03 KB/s
 2050K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 99%    3.05 MB/s
 2100K ....                                                  100%    4.16 MB/s

17:59:09 (538.59 KB/s) - `195000.jpg' saved [2154765/2154765]

--17:59:20--  http://undisclosed_site.com/LinkOne/195000.jpg
           => `195000.jpg.1'
Resolving undisclosed_site.com... public_ip
Connecting to undisclosed_site[public_ip]:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK

Length: 2,154,765 [image/jpeg]

    0K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  2%    5.74 KB/s
   50K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  4%    1.62 KB/s
  100K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  7%    8.14 KB/s
  150K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  9%   14.10 KB/s
      200K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 11%    5.10 KB/s
  250K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 14%   11.07 KB/s
  300K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 16%    2.68 KB/s
  350K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 19%   15.38 KB/s
  400K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 21%    8.38 KB/s
  450K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 23%   17.98 KB/s
  500K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 26% 1007.93 B/s
  550K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 28%    3.18 KB/s
  600K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 30%   12.90 KB/s
  650K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 33%   12.85 KB/s
  700K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 35%   15.76 KB/s
  750K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 38%   16.93 KB/s
  800K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 40%    1.39 KB/s
  850K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 42%    5.72 KB/s
  900K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 45%    5.21 KB/s
  950K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 47%   13.73 KB/s
 1000K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 49%   11.60 KB/s
 1050K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 52%   11.90 KB/s
 1100K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 54%   69.54 KB/s
 1150K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 57%   17.58 KB/s
 1200K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 59%    5.98 KB/s
 1250K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 61%   10.29 KB/s
 1300K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 64%    1.19 KB/s
 1350K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 66%    5.50 KB/s
 1400K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 68%   13.68 KB/s
 1450K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 71%  769.74 B/s
 1500K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 73%    4.69 KB/s
 1550K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 76%    1.64 KB/s
 1600K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 78%    7.26 KB/s
 1650K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 80%    9.79 KB/s
 1700K .......... .......... .......... .......... ...
```

Comment: More details please. These are both executed over the same company network, are they? Is this reproducable?

Answer (score 1):

> Any ideas would be helpful.

Your internal company network is shared with other people whose activities may cause occasional congestion. If there is a network manager, she may be able to identify the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you are saying that when you use the servers internal addreess e.g. 192.168.8.69 the wget works quickly.  However when you use the servers publicly routable IP address e.g. 75.34.275.123 the wget works much slower.  If this is the question you are asking it depends on how you have your routing set up.  Here we have the gateway router configured that if it sees a request going out for one of our servers addresses it turns it right back around and sends it to the internal address.  If your router is not set up that way then the request to the publicly routeable address is going out to the internet and back into the server producing the difference in the wget times.  Or if you are using the servers web address it would depend on DNS.  If you are not running DNS inside the network then the request has to go out to DNS for resolution and then back.